# Prevent UITableViewCell layout during animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have an `UIViewController` with an `UITableView` inside of an `UINavigationController`.
When I hide the navigation bar with

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

the table view is resized and a new cell is displayed at the bottom. 
This cell layouts it's subviews inside of the animation that hides the navigation bar.

[image: Cell Animation]

Is there a way to exclude the layout of the cell from the animation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can prevent the cell from animating by implementing the UITableViewDelegate method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` as such:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
        [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly for everything but the disclosure indicator. Using `performWithoutAnimation:` around `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;` fixed also that.